# How to get skewness and kurtosis using Julia

Tags: statistics, julia, skew, kurtosis

I'm working on pointcloud lidar data. I want to calculate skewness and kurtosis to distinguish road from ground. My current intensity column looks like this in plot [image] Is there an implementation on another language? I read

> First, the skewness of the point cloud is calculated. If it is
> greater than zero, peaks dominate the point cloud distribution as
> shown in Table 1. Thus, the highest value of the point cloud is re-
> moved by classifying it as an object point. To separate all ground
> and object points, these steps are iteratively executed while the
> skewness of the point cloud is greater than zero.

UPDATE

I tried
the following code but its an infinite loop

I'm getting `StatsBase.skewness(poi.intensity)` around 0.125

```
data = rand(Gamma(7.5, 1.0), 75)
th=maximum(data)
classification=rand(2:3,length(data))
poi=Table(intensity=data,classification=classification)
while sk > 0
    poi.classification[findall(poi.intensity .== th)] .= 7 #object
    th = th .- 1
    sk = skewness(poi.intensity[findall(poi.classification .== 2)])
    print(sk)
end
```

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible. Please provide a minimal example and explain your expected output as well.

Comment: @Shayan I'm not sure how to generate skewed data. rnd is naturally normally distributed.

Comment: What if you use a Chi2 distribution (e.g. with k=3 ) by `Distributions.jl`?

Comment: have you tried StatsBase.jl's skewness(array) and kurtosis(array) on your data?

Comment: The instructions as you quote them may not work to classify the ground versus the road, because the instructions are directed at looking for objects, such as cars, trees, or signs, that are elevated above ground.  But the ground and the road may be the same elevation, and the main difference is that the road is probably flatter, so that the skewness __locally__ on the road might be lower than on non-level ground?